# Attacking through an open but not listened port

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention, ports

Let us say, we open a port, say port 123, so that upon listening, an application on the server can receive incoming packets through the port 123.

If there is no way that an inside application on the server listens the port 123, how can an attacker use this open port to attack the server?

Comment: Simply put, they don't.

Comment: @MechMK1 they don't? or they can't?

Comment: I'll turn the question around: What makes you think they can?

Comment: A port isn't open unless it's being listened on, but one can't listen without any ears (i.e., without any application `bind()`ing the port).

Comment: @Will If I don't have any idea whether someone can or can't, it is logical to assume that they can, and that is the reason why I am asking; to learn it.

Comment: That's not how logic works. "I have no idea if my slipper can make me fly, therefore it is logical to assume it can."

Comment: What you need to learn is how ports work.

Comment: @schroeder Ok, let's analyse your logic then; if we assume that no can attack and someone attacks, we are busted and (probably) lost millions of dollars. However, if we assume that someone might and put some additional security measures, but then it turn out that no one can, we overworked unnecessarily. If, to you, doing the latter is "illogical", then I accept, I am illogical.

Comment: @schroeder Curiosity? have you heard of it?

Comment: That's not how that works. You do not "logically assume". As you say, you are ***curious*** to learn more. It's called a "hypothesis", not a "logical assumption". Just because you don't logically assume it *can* doesn't mean you logically assume *it can't*. Therefore, MechMK1's question is apt: what prompted your hypothesis, aside from ignorance leading to fear?

Comment: oh dude, how did you become a moderator. Just delete all the comment, I have nothing to say

Comment: @onurcanbektas Wow, if this is how you treat the people you ask to help you, then you will not go far in life.

Comment: OTOH, when you answer, a notice appears saying "onurcanbektas is a new contributor, be nice". It is pretty difficult to understand how this community works at first, so don't worry. What I suggest is doing a lot of research before asking a question, also using the search function on this community to find related or duplicate questions.

Comment: Now a quick answer to your question: if you open a port, but there are no services listening to that port, then nothing happens. Whether you open that port or not is then irrelevant. However it is still considered a best practice to keep ports closed. Why? Because of defense in depth. What if one day you install a misconfigured local web server for development and you forget to close the ports? As you can see, as a precaution, you'd better keep a port closed even if nothing is using it at the moment.

Comment: @reed thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no application listening to a port, the operating system will reject incoming packages sent to this port. So no attack is possible related to intrusion into the system via this port.